# Checking eigenstates of the helicity operator

Tags: field-theory, spinors, helicity

In Peskin & Schroeder's book, the helicity operator is defined as
$$
h = \hat{p} \cdot \mathbf{S} = \dfrac{1}{2} \hat{p}_i \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\sigma^i & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma^i \end{array}\right)
$$
and it is stated that the solutions to the Dirac equation in the large boost limit, i.e., massless particles,
$$
\sqrt{2E} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \end{array}\right) \quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt{2E} \left(\begin{array}{c} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) \\ 0 \end{array}\right)\ ,
$$
are indeed eigenstates of such helicity operator.

However, either I am confused with the notation or how the operator acts on spinors and the $\sqrt{2E}$ factor, because I'm not able to see how to act with $h$ on these spinors and get the corresponding eigenvalues.

Any help on this will be appreciated. I have already read other related questions about the helicity operator, but didn't find any where the exact calculation on how to operate with these spinors is made.

**Edit on the possible solution**

I found that the operator $\hat{p}_i$ actually means $p_i / |\mathbf{p}|$. Then, if $p_i$ is the usual momentum operator, I would have that
$$
\hat{p}_i = \dfrac{-i \partial_i}{\sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2}}
$$

Thus, my guess is that I was missing the wave-like part of the solution, i.e., the factor $e^{-i p \cdot x}$, which is the one that will interact with the derivatives $\partial_i$.

Now, since these solutions are given from the assumption that the particle moves along the $z$ direction only, we would have that
$$
\hat{p}_i = \dfrac{-i}{p_z}  \partial_i \quad\text{and}\quad e^{-i p\cdot x} = e^{-i(Et - p_z z)}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
h \left[ \sqrt{2E} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \end{array}\right) e^{-i p \cdot x} \right] &= \dfrac{-i}{2} \dfrac{\sqrt{2E}}{p_z} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) \partial_x + \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ i \end{array}\right) \partial_y + \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \partial_z \end{array}\right) e^{-i(Et - p_z z)} \\[10pt]
&= \dfrac{-i}{2} \dfrac{\sqrt{2E}}{p_z} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ i p_z \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \end{array}\right) e^{-i(Et - p_z z)} \\[10pt]
&= \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2E} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \end{array}\right) e^{-i p \cdot x}
\end{align}
$$
meaning that, indeed, it was an eigenstate of $h$ with eigenvalue $1/2$.

I would appreciate if anyone can verify that this is a correct solution on how to act with the helicity operator.

Comment: Shouldn't those spinors have four components in them? The operator is a $4\times4$ matrix, the spinors are $4\times 1$ matrices what seems to be the issue?

Comment: @Triatticus Those spinors have four components. I used the notation in P&S's book, in which the isolated zeros means that the other two components are null.

Comment: $\hat{p} $ is a regular unit $vector$ pointing in the direction of the particle momentum. Here the particle is boosted in the 3 - direction, i.e. in a momentum eigenstate having only a $p^3$ momentum component, so $\hat{p}\cdot \mathbf{S} =\frac{1}{2}\cdot1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^3 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma^3
 \\
\end{pmatrix} $